# Auto mount & Permissions on a new hard drive

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive

I have added a new SATA hard drive to my Ubuntu machine and I would like to auto mount and change the permissions on the drive so I can write to it.

I have tried following one of the Ubuntu guides for help to auto mount but I'm not having any luck. Also the read and write permissions change should be easy in terminal but I can't find anything.

Can anyone help this newbie please?

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal window...

```
gksudo nautilus
```

this opens a file view with root permissions.
Right click on the drive you want to change permissions and select properties then permissions.
You can now change the permissions to your username and group from the drop down lists.

Answer (score 0):

first do this sudo fdisk -l

you will get a list of drives
like this

/dev/sda1              63    47182904    23591421    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        47183872    51183615     1999872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3   *    51183616    71184383    10000384   83  Linux
/dev/sda4        71184384   156366847    42591232    b  W95 FAT32

so to automount /dev/sda1

type this command first

gksudo gedit /etc/fstab

it will open fstab with gedit

now add this line to it

/dev/sda1   /media/20gb  ntfs    defaults    0   0

Here,
/dev/sda1 is your drive

/media/20gb is a directory where you want to mount your drive
but you need to make this directory before

ntfs is type of file system of your drive

defaults    0   0 are permissions.

this is for automount and for prmissions i am also searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

> PySDM is a PyGTK-based Storage Device Manager that allows full
>   customization of hard disk mount points without the need to edit fstab
>   manually. It also allows the creation of udev rules for dynamic
>   configuration of storage devices.

Search for it in the Software Centre... nice and easy GUI...

Once installed search for STORAGE DEVICE MANAGER in your apps list...